# multi-threaded website parser and out of memory problems

Tags: java, concurrency, jsoup, apache-commons-httpclient, gpars

Hi.
I'm coding a website parser that is aimed to be fast and thus multi-threaded.
The external libraries I'm using are: apache HTTP client, Jsoup (for HTML parsing) and GPars (for message-driven threads).
Now I'll show some concept that I'm trying to implement

```java
static StaticDispatchActor<String> httpActor;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        int numThreads = 25;
        try{
            numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Number of threads defaulted to "+numThreads);
        }
        final int numberOfThreads = numThreads;
        final ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        final Async async = Async.newInstance().use(threadpool);
        AtomicInteger jobCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
//.....
// This is a parser itself which parses usernames out of every page.
        Actor jsoupUser = new StaticDispatchActor<String>(){ // actor to parse users
            HashSet<String> users = new HashSet<>(); // found users
            public void onMessage(String html){ // takes html -> adds parsed users 2 set
                users.addAll(Jsoup.parse(html)
                    .select("a[href*=/profile/]").stream() // select links
                    .map(e -> e.text()) // extract usernames
                    .filter(s -> s.length() > 0) // empty lines -> out
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
                System.out.print("Users: "+users.size()+", Jobs: "+jobCount.get()+"\r");

            }
        }.start();
// This actor shall extract new links to parse out of every page
        Actor jsoupLinker = new StaticDispatchActor<String>(){ // link extractor
            HashSet<String> usedLinks = new HashSet<>(); // already found links
            public synchronized void removeBack(String url){

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String html) {
                Set<String> links =  Jsoup.parse(html).select("a[href]").stream().parallel()
                .map(e -> e.attr("href").replace("#comments", "")// here also some replacements...
                )
                .filter(s -> (!usedLinks.contains(s) && /* other filters */ )
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                links.forEach(url -> httpActor.send(url)); // send to process new URLs
            }
        }.start(); // start actor
// this actor is the processor of new links and where the error comes in:
httpActor = new StaticDispatchActor<String>(){ // process responses async
            public void onMessage(String url) {
                try{
                while(jobCount.get()>numberOfThreads); // wait for running threads to be less than wanted value; without this number of running jobs goes out of any control
                async.execute(Request.Get(defaultWebSiteUrl+url), new FutureCallback<Content>(){ @Override // do request and process async
                    public void completed(Content c) {
                        jobCount.decrementAndGet();
                        try{
                        String s = c.asString();
                        jsoupUser.send(s);
                        jsoupLinker.send(s);
                        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e1){
                            System.out.println("out of my memory, "); // This is the thrown error the question is about - [1]
                        }
                    }

            @Override public void failed(Exception e) {
                        jobCount.decrementAndGet();
                        try {
                            throw e;
                        } catch (ConnectException e4){ // if the request is timed out resend it
                            httpActor.send(url);
                            System.out.println("resent\r\n");
                        } catch (HttpResponseException e0){

                        } catch (Exception e1) { // for all other exceptions
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            @Override public void cancelled() {
                jobCount.decrementAndGet(); // never done actually
            }
        });
            jobCount.incrementAndGet();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e3){
            System.out.println("some illigal shit");
        }
    }
};
httpActor.start();
```

Now the problem is, although I limited a number of running jobs, my code somehow goes out of memory (search for [1] in the code to see where).
Maybe you have any idea on how to resolve it. Or there is some showcase for similar task, because I fill very wrong about the whole application design and maybe I should change it at all?
Thank you.

Comment: By far the easiest way to figure out what's going on is to make the VM create a memory dump on OOME (`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`) and then analyse it with [this tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

So, using **BiziClop**'s tip, I was able to figure out the mistake.
If some is interested, I, as you can see above, was sending HTML code received from server as a string to 2 different actors and than, inside these actors, parsing them. That was the cause for all out-of-memory errors, since these HTML pages are pretty big especially given how many of them are waiting to be processed in the message queue.
The solution I used is just parse the document and select needed elements and transfer their list to matching actors for further processing.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(c.asString());
jsoupUser.send(doc.select("a[href*=/profile/]"));
jsoupLinker.send(doc.select("a[href]"));
```

Still, if any one has anything to say about how to improve the algorithm I'll really appreciate it.